# Push notification badge increase and php script

Tags: iphone, badge

I send push notification to my device with php script from my server. The script code is

```
<?php    
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'a14b6212fa69a2b1c2dde4547a50c711fd40b9787cc029800584890d72a9f5db';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ujyfljnhjgby123';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Delivery 33 message!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'badge' => +1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .       $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

In my AppDelegate.m there is such code

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];

 }
```

The question is - why number in my badge is not updating when I receive more than one notification? Looks like its just replace

```
'badge' => +1,
```

each time. What am I doing wrong? Can you please help? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it from the server side. In my case I have done it through php and mysql. Here is my database 
[image]

I have added a field badgecount and i increase the badge count every time i send the push to the device with this code

```
    $query = "SELECT badgecount FROM pushnotifications WHERE device_token = '{$device_token}'";
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $updatequery = "update pushnotifications set badgecount=badgecount+1 WHERE device_token ='{$device_token}'";
    $updatequery = $this->db->query($updatequery);
    $device = $device_token;
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $pushmessage, 'badge' =>$row["badgecount"]+1, 'sound' => 'default');
    $payload = json_encode($payload);
```

And I also make another api for making the badgcount 0 which is called in the

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

So when the notification is seen it is again zero in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass relative values for `badge` in the payload. +1 will simply become 1. If you want to increment or decrement you will need to keep track of the current badge number on your server, and pass the new absolute value in the payload.

Comment: So you mean I need to send to server my current badge number?

Comment: If you alter the badge number from within the application, yes. For example, when the user opens an unread message in your app, you need to update the badge number. Then tell the server the new badge number, or perhaps let it mark the message as read and let it figure out the correct badge number.The implementation of this depends on what kind of app it is and how your server API's are structured.

Comment: @Rengers can  you elaborate more on that, Im facing this issue now. I just dont know how to keep track of that badge count on my server

Comment: How you track the badge count is entirely up to you. For a simple app I did we had a database table with device ID's and their current badge counts. When we had to send a new notification, we incremented the count and included that in the payload. Then when a notification was dismissed from the app, the app would send a request to the server with the new badge count. The server would then update the matching record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this, but +1 will just say 1, I think you need '+1'.

```
$body['aps'] = array(
'badge' => '+1',
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);
```

EDIT: Actually, this may just be for UrbanAirship now that I think about it...

Answer (score -1):

First register for notification with the following method in the appDelegate.m

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devicetoken { 

Check the reponse here

}
```

Comment: I have that method. I can receive notification, my problem is the number on badge dont increase when I send more than 1 notification